# Careers technologies drop-down error

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

When filling out my profile in Careers, I entered a couple of "Technologies" and the drop-down box would not go away. I saved the "Technologies" choices thinking that might help, but it did not. It didn't go away when I tried to edit the next section either. This is what it looked like:

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: I went back and tried to duplicate the problem but couldn't so maybe it was a fluke. But, as you can see from the screenshot, something odd happened there.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>See the red text "Missing end year" next to the save button? That's your problem. You only entered a month for the end of the time frame.</strike>

Yes, I agree that's wrong and maybe unrelated to the time frame error. But I can't get a repro, so, not sure.

Comment: Nope... the problem existed before I even started filling out the Experience section. I couldn't fill out the time frame section because I couldn't see it with the drop-box in front of it. I could tab into the fields behind that section but not see what I was typing.

Comment: I spoke too fast. Yes, that's weird.